# How to send transformed data from partitions to S3?

Tags: apache-spark

I have an `RDD` which is to big to `collect`.  I have applied a chain of transformations to the `RDD` and want to send its transformed data directly from its partitions on my slaves to S3.  I am currently operating as follows:

```
val rdd:RDD = initializeRDD
val rdd2 = rdd.transform
rdd2.first // in order to force calculation of RDD
rdd2.foreachPartition sendDataToS3
```

Unfortunately, the data that gets sent to S3 is untransformed.  The `RDD` looks exactly like it did in stage `initializeRDD`.

Here is the body of sendDataToS3:

```
implicit class WriteableRDD[T](rdd:RDD[T]){

def transform:RDD[String] = rdd map {_.toString}

....
def sendPartitionsToS3(prefix:String) = {
  rdd.foreachPartition { p =>
    val filename = prefix+new scala.util.Random().nextInt(1000000)
    val pw = new PrintWriter(new File(filename))
    p foreach pw.println
    pw.close
    s3.putObject(S3_BUCKET, filename, new File(filename))
  }
  this
}

}
```

This is called with `rdd.transform.sendPartitionsToS3(prefix)`.

**How do I make sure the data that gets sent in `sendDataToS3` is the transformed data?**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: are you able to save transformed data from a `foreachPartition` closure, perhaps passing it to S3?

Comment: I haven't tried S3 but transformed data is correctly passed to and from the function.

Comment: When I collect my RDD, the data is transformed.  When I send it to S3 from the `foreachPartition` block, it is not.

Comment: I give up. I don't think it possible to reproduce this in general so either is matter of some strange issue in your code or you are hitting a really strange bug.

Comment: thanks for trying -- i may rewrite this question and repost

Answer (score 3):

My guess is there is a bug in your code that is not included in the question.

I'm answering anyway just to make sure you are aware of `RDD.saveAsTextFile`. You can give it a path on S3 (`s3n://bucket/directory`) and it will write each partition into that path directly from the executors.

I can hardly imagine when you would need to implement your own `sendPartitionsToS3` instead of using `saveAsTextFile`.